# Why is bishop to h8 the best move in this position?

Tags: opening, analysis, beginner, kings-indian

[image]

I don't understand how that move is a good move, much less the best move according to this chess.com analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture already answers the question:

If you play any other move but **...Bh8**, for example **...d6**, White will answer **g4** and trap your knight. Some exchanges can be thrown in before he can capture (**dxe5**, **Qxd1** etc.), but ultimately, there's no escape.

**...Bh8** by itself is indeed not a desirable move (moves a developed piece again, to a square with less influence), but here it's a tactical necessity to save that knight (which is more valuable than losing a move or two) by vacating an escape square.

Since White is behind in development, Black can actually afford to give that tempo without major damage (+0.31, says the computer).

Answer (score 6):

The knight on h5 has no retreat squares, which means the threat of White playing g2-g4 is on the cards. The move **... Bh8** then frees up the g7 square so the knight has a retreat square should it be attacked.